# Codeigniter select SUM give mysqld cpu high

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I'm still facing issue with calculating total sum amount of transaction, while it return the total sum it keep cpu high.

[Cpu usage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Djeuc.png)

Model class code

```
public function get_topup_sender_balance()
{

$this->db->select('SUM(total) as total');
$this->db->from('transactions');
$array = array('sender' => $this->session->id, 'status' => 'Processed', 'payment_type' => 'Topup', 'payment_method' => 'BalanceTopup');
$this->db->where($array);
$this->db->group_by('id');
$res = $this->db->get();
if($res->num_rows() > 0)
{
    return round($res->result(),2);
}else{
     return '0';
}
```

}

Helper custom library

```
public function transaction_balance() {

    $sender_topup = $this->CI->myac_model->get_topup_sender_balance();
    return number_format($sender_topup, 2, '.', '');
}
```

On Controller class and views page i call $this->helper_api->transaction_balance() to get customer balance and is return well balance but mysqld cpu will be high

And on mysql logs i get

```
# Query_time: 0.353698  Lock_time: 0.000111 Rows_sent: 0  Rows_examined: 484565
SET timestamp=1543791344;
SELECT SUM(total) as total
FROM `transactions`
WHERE `sender` = '4'
AND `status` = 'Processed'
AND `payment_type` = 'Topup'
AND `payment_method` = 'BalanceTopup'
GROUP BY `id`;
```

Any solution/idea to solve this pleases.

Comment: Considering that it examined nearly half a million records and took about 1/3 of a second I wouldn't worry too much about the cpu usage. Chances are a good portion of that cpu time was used by the profiler.

Comment: @DFriend it take slow site if i check the balance, other pages work well.

Comment: post your mysql create code for your table - do you have proper indices ? the next thing which comes to mind - `round()` expects a float - `result()` however returns always an array with objects - so your line `return round($res->result(),2);` won't work anyway.

Comment: Hello @sintakonte i have tried to return result on array but the problem is still and my site is still slow.